# almost same mass, same distance, different energy needs

Tags: energy, mass, energy-conservation, work

Imagine a car, driving 10 km at constant speed in 6th gear. There will be a measurable fuel consumption.

Now imagine the same car driving 10 km again at a constant speed (same as above) in the 1st gear. The fuel consumption will be MUCH higher.

I would expect a higher consumption because the internal organs of the engine make more rotations and therefor "travel" a longer distance. But the real consumption will be really much higher then the one i would expect since the moving organs of an engine are RELATIVELY lightweight compared to a car.

Now, $W = F \cdot d$, there is no relation to speed, just the distance.
$P = W / t$ but since the speed is the same in both cases also $t$ should be the same in both cases.

So why does the car in the first gear use up so much more fuel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your premise is correct: driving the same car at the same speed on the same road will require the same usable power output from the engine.  And doing it in first gear will consume much more fuel than doing it in sixth gear.  Because...

The engine consumes fuel and converts ***most*** of it into heat. The engine then converts a portion of that heat into energy delivered to the wheels.

Using the 6-th gear operation as the baseline:

1. The higher revving engine will not burn the fuel as efficiently as baseline.  Air and fuel will not have the time to mix and burn completely.   The catalytic converter will get a lot hotter.and/or the exhaust will become richer in CO and unburned hydrocarbons.
2. The energy needed to run the engine will go up.  During the run there will be more electricity consumed from the alternator to run the ignition system (more rev means more sparks).  The electrical air fan will need to run more (see below).
3. There will be more friction in the engine as the parts move over one-another at higher speeds.  This heat represents more energy wasted from the fuel.  The heat will need to be removed from the engine.  Oil pumps, water pumps and radiator cooling will all need to work harder, and they all get their energy from the fuel.

Make it personal:  Why do you slow down on a bicycle going up a hill?  Because you need to match the power needed to the power your body can produce.  Why do you shift gears, rather than just pedaling slower?  Because your body has that power output over a very small range of comfortable strokes/minute.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you've answered your own question:

> I would expect a higher consumption because the internal organs of the engine make more rotations and therefor "travel" a longer distance

This is more or less right. Each revolution of your pistons equals a burn in the cylinder. Since the car burns the same amount of fuel with each cycle, then running your engine at a higher rpm necessarily means you are burning more fuel!

A car running in 1st gear at, say 30 mph, would be likely be running near 6000 rpms. A car running in 6th gear at the same speed would be running around 1200 rpms. Running in 1st gear, in this particular (and not necessarily accurate) case here, uses about 5 times as much fuel as running in 6th gear.

However, I believe that there are 'tricks' your computerized engine can due to change the actual fuel consumption dependent on what gear you are in, what speed you are traveling, rpms, etc. So the actual difference might be less than that ratio I gave.

Comment: yeah, but whats with the excess energy? i am somewhat missing something here.. why does the same mass at the same speed for the same distance use more energy? if i put more energy in it should be going faster, or beeing accelerating till the wind resistance brings it into balance. where is all this excess energy going? all in heat?

Comment: It takes more energy to rotate your gears at 6000 rpm as compared to 1200 rpm, no? There's your excess energy.